# Ionic React Typescript with pug.js, 'Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined' when use tsx but not jsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pug, capacitor, ionic-react

Problem: `react-app-rewired start` works on App.jsx (and .js too) but not on App.tsx (and .ts too)

Steps

1. I created a boilerplate app with `ionic start my-app blank --type=react --capacitor`
2. on package.json, i replace and reinstall accordingly (remove package.lock.json, `npm i`)

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
-       "start": "ionic serve",
+       "start": "react-app-rewired start",
-       "build": "ionic build",
+       "build": "react-app-rewired build",
        "test": "react-scripts test"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.3",
        "@capacitor/core": "2.4.3",
        "@ionic/react": "^5.0.7",
        "@ionic/react-router": "^5.0.7",
        "ionicons": "^5.0.0",
        "react": "^16.13.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
        "react-router": "^5.1.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
+       "babel-plugin-transform-react-pug": "^7.0.1",
+       "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
+       "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.6",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.3",
        "@ionic/cli": "6.12.2",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^8.0.3",
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.25",
        "@types/node": "^12.12.24",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.17",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
        "@types/react-router": "^5.1.4",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
        "typescript": "3.8.3"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project"
```

3. add `config-overrides.js` file on the project's root folder

```js
const { override, disableEsLint, addBabelPlugin } = require('customize-cra')

module.exports = override(
    disableEsLint(),
    addBabelPlugin('transform-react-pug'),
)
```

4. Replace App.tsx with

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    IonApp,
    IonContent,
    IonHeader,
    IonTitle,
    IonToolbar,
} from '@ionic/react'

declare const pug: any
const App: React.FC = () => {
    return pug`
        IonApp
            IonHeader
                IonToolbar
                    IonTitle My App
            IonContent.ion-padding Add some content here…
    `
}
export default App
```

5. On `tsconfig.json` set `"strict": false`
6. `npm start` (or `react-app-rewired start`) on project root folder

There's no error on terminal ('Compiled successfully!'), chrome screen is blank, on chrome console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at App (main.chunk.js:33)
    ...
```

Strangely, the app works fine if I change the App extension with .jsx or .js instead of .tsx or .ts

The pug setup also works when setting up a CRA typescript app instead of a `ionic start --type=react --capacitor` app

Edit:
Here is the github for the working/not working repo https://github.com/calvindio/template-ionic-react-ts-pug

Comment: I guess the problem with the webpack, set strict mode to true, also, the APP() function is not typed, make sure you put the right types to this function

Comment: I tried setting the strict mode to true too, same result. And there's no typescript error. I haven't understand webpack. Because I avoided ejecting the app, I used react-app-rewired, customize-cra, and babel-plugin-transform-react-pug as a workaround

Comment: I put `const App: React.FC = () => {...` when in tsx too. Also same error.

Comment: in the package you have 2 start command and 2 builds, delete one of them

Comment: It's a notation I use to indicate I replace `"start": "ionic serve",` with `"start": "react-app-rewired start",` (CMIIW). I only use the 'react-app-rewired' version for both start and build. Thank you for being so attentive.

Comment: Can you share your working example repo as well?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/calvindio/template-ionic-react-ts-pug. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue

It looks like the issue is from `tsc` deleted the unused import which ended up the issue.

For example, this line `import React from 'react'` won't get included in the compiled code since you didn't return as `jsx` format.

Likewise, all the import like `import { IonApp, ... } from '@ionic/react';` won't be included in the compiled code either. That's why `webpack` can't map `React` import correctly.

#### Solution

From my understanding, I've yet been aware of any option of `tsc` would still keep the unused imports in the built code. It would be great if you could find that option.

But for now, you could work around by using `require` keyword which keeps thing sill be imported:

`App.tsx`

```js
const React = require('react');
const { IonApp, ... } = require('@ionic/react');

// ...
```

Comment: Wow, it's solved! Thank you! Your explanation makes sense. I wonder if there's a vscode extension for autoimport using the `require` instead of `import`. Again thank you!

Comment: For those reading in the future: you can use a combination of normal auto import extension and the use import-to-require-converter (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tlevesque.import-to-require&ssr=false#overview)

Comment: I'm still keen to keep using `esnext` style which means using `import` but then we can configure like allow unused import to deal with kind of situation (it's all about related to `tsc`)

Comment: After a day of use, I also really want to use `import`. The amount of manually converting auto `import` to `const require` is a lot. Is it something in the tsconfig?

Comment: Can you try to research about how to keep unused import in Typescript which is available here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html? Or as long as somehow you could make your import used where you used pug as template, then it would work normally

Comment: It's this flag here https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#importsNotUsedAsValues. I set it to "preserve", but it still can't find React (and other imports too) :(. Seems like the elision of imports is still happening.